# Uniswap: get token price for USDC in solidity

Tags: solidity, usdc, uniswapv2

I try to create a function in Solidity which returns the amount of a ERC20 token for a set amount of USDC.

For that I go through the following steps:

1. Get the address of the pair.

   address pairAddress = IUniswapV2Factory(uniswapV2Factory).getPair(erc20Contract, USDC);

   require(pairAddress != address(0), "Invalid Uniswap Pair");
2. Get the reserves of both coins:

   IUniswapV2Pair pair = IUniswapV2Pair(pairAddress);

   (uint reserve0, uint reserve1, ) = pair.getReserves();
3. Check that I am using the right reserves.

   if (IUniswapV2Pair(pairAddress).token0() == USDC) {
   reserve_usdc = reserve0;
   reserve_coin = reserve1;
   } else {
   reserve_usdc = reserve1;
   reserve_coin = reserve0;
   }
4. Calculate the amount of erc20 token I get for the input amount of USDC token.

   uint256 price = (reserve_usdc * (10 ** 18)) / reserve_coin;

   uint256 erc20_amount = (usdc_amount * price) / (10 ** 6);

However the returned amount is nothing like the one on Uniswap.
I checked the pairAddress and it seems correct. I am unsure of where exactly my problem lies here. So any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: I think you're forgetting about the 0.3% fee. You can check the formula uniswap is using here https://github.com/Uniswap/v2-periphery/blob/master/contracts/libraries/UniswapV2Library.sol#L43